# How to calculate Week in jQuery DatePicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Is there any examples on how to return the week number of the selected date in DatePicker into another input type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I got the solution**

```
$( "#pickdate" ).datepicker({ 
     onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        alert($.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)))
     } 
});
```

**I think this will generate a week number for sure.**

Answer (score 1):

The [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library is good for this sort of thing (as well as a lot of other date calculations). Check out the [`getWeek()`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation) function.

Comment: There's never a need for a library for just one simple task. Unfortunately most programs consist of just a whole bunch of "one simple tasks"

Comment: most way is sometimes not the right way, and most programs today wont add a js plugin just to calc a week num.

Comment: I got the solution 

        $( "#pickdate" ).datepicker({            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {alert($.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)))}        });      


I think this will generate a week number.

Comment: Good solution if you're already using the JQuery datepicker. By the way, it's usually best to post the solution as an answer to your own question, rather than burying it in the comments.